# Extrapolate python array with unequal spacing between elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, extrapolation

I have two sets of large arrays (here I have shortened them):

```
x1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

y1 = [0.2, 0.19, 0.22, 0.18, 0.22, 0.21]

x2 = [0, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.7, 3.5, 6, 10]

y2 = [5, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 5.2, 4, 4.6, 4, 4.3, 3.9]
```

Thus three things can be noticed about the above arrays:

1. x1 and y1 have 6 values but x2 and y2 have 10 values (the exact numbers do not matter, the only thing that matters is that x2 and y2 have many more values than x1 and y1).
2. x1 is spaced evenly while x2 is not.
3. The x arrays begin and end at the same values.

How do I  create a **new array with the extrapolated values of y1 at all the values of x2?**

It is also important to notice that y1 has potential values that will not be included in the new array, for instance in the above example, y1[4] is not needed because it does not fall at a value of x2.

Also notice that y2 has nothing to do with this particular problem, I just provided it for overall understanding.

I have tried using the approach that Jblasco developed for a similar problem here: [interpolate python array to minimize maximum difference between elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612340/interpolate-python-array-to-minimize-maximum-difference-between-elements) however my problem is somewhat different than the one posed in that link.

Comment: I think you meant _inferred_, not _interpolated_.

Comment: Actually, I think the term is _extrapolated_. Sorry about that!

Comment: Based on the wikipedia definition I think that this would still be interpolation. Am I wrong?

Comment: This isn't a question. Even if you edited it slightly to make it a question, I think the typical response would be *"What have you tried so far?"*

Comment: Thanks CoDEmanX for the format editing. Also, DaoWen, you are right, this is not a question. This is my first question, do I need to have an actual question?

Comment: If you want an answer then you need a question. Specific questions tend to get a better response than general questions like *"How do I implement this?"* Also, as I've already mentioned, it helps to post what you've already tried, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok thanks DaoWen, I tried to turn it into a question and I provided what I had already done.

Comment: y1 does not have six values, it has five.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake ebarr, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to just be a straightforward interpolation/extrapolation problem.

```
import numpy as np

#here y2 is the new extrapolated array
y2 = np.interp(x2,x1,y1)
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. You are right this works perfectly. Thanks.